# ASP.NET Core EF Many to Many referencing table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a user with contacts table. I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way as there is a column added which I didn't declare.

The entities:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ContactUserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public User ContactUser { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.ContactUserId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
        .HasOne(x => x.User)
        .WithMany(x => x.Contacts)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
        .HasOne(x => x.ContactUser)
        .WithMany(x => x.Contacts)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ContactUserId);
}
```

The result:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Contact",
    columns: table => new
    {
        UserId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        ContactUserId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        UserId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Contact", x => new { x.UserId, x.ContactUserId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Contact_User_ContactUserId",
            column: x => x.ContactUserId,
            principalTable: "User",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Contact_User_UserId1",
            column: x => x.UserId1,
            principalTable: "User",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    });
```

The real question:

Where is the column UserId1 in contact coming from? Is there something wrong with my definition? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do a n:n or 1:n relationship? From your model it looks like you have 1 User with n Contacts, which isn't many to many but one to many, if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: @HotTowelie It's 1:n to `Contact`, then n:1 to `Contact.ContactUser`. So, `User` is n:n to *itself*.

Comment: Might be related: `User.Contacts` cannot be both the navigation property from `User` to its `ContactUser`s *and* the navigation property going the other way at he same time.  One of those should be configured out from the `User` entity, and the other configured with the parameterless `HasMany()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you ended up with an additional *UserId1* on contact table is because you are specifying the other side of both *User* and *ContactUser* associations on Contact object to be *Contacts* on User object which is incorrect. As a result, EF ignores it and creates yet another association for *Contacts* on User object and map it to *UserId1* column on Contact table.

One way to fix this is to create another list of Contacts on User object and map it accordingly:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> ContactUsers { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
    .HasOne(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(x => x.Contacts)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
    .HasOne(x => x.ContactUser)
    .WithMany(x => x.ContactUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ContactUserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Which yields the desired schema:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much and also thumbs up for the OnDelete addition!